# Is there a web framework for kotlin native

Tags: web-frameworks, kotlin-native

I want to create an app exposing a web server with a REST API in Kotlin Native, but I can't find any recent project or lib.
There's [kwang](https://github.com/KwangIO/kwang) but it doesn't seems to be maintained anymore and it depends on another C library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ktor 1.4 (WIP) will support Kotlin/Native as a Server .

https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/571#issuecomment-562118651

Kotlin/Native is Beta for now , so There is a long way to go

Comment: as of ktor:1.5.3 native is only supported for ktor-client

Answer (score -2):

Yes! [Alpas](https://alpas.dev) - it's a newer framework and is inspired by the Laravel framework for PHP. Out-of-the-box, it will get your rolling with databases and authentication.

Comment: Well, it's not kotlin native compatible, it still requires Java to run.

Comment: Yes. Run's as a fat jar and requires JVM/JRE... Would love to have a real native solution.